# Find what unknown function does in C using gdb

Tags: c, gdb

I have a function m(int i, char c) which takes and returns a char between "-abc...xyz" and also takes an integer i.

Basically I have no way to see the source code of the function but can call it and get the return value. Using gdb/C, what's the best way to decipher what the function actually does? I've tried looking for patterns using consecutive chars and integer inputs but have come up with nothing yet.

If it helps, here are some results of testing the return values, with the first two bits being the arguments and the last bit being the return value:

```
0 a    i
0 b    l
0 c    t
0 d    x
0 e    f
0 f    v

1 a    q
1 b    i
1 c    y
1 d    e

2 a    a
2 b    y
2 c    f
2 d    n
```

disassembly provides the following:

```
0x00014354 <m+0>:    save  %sp, -144, %sp
0x00014358 <m+4>:    st  %i0, [ %fp + 0x44 ]
0x0001435c <m+8>:    mov  %i1, %g1
0x00014360 <m+12>:   stb  %g1, [ %fp + 0x48 ]
0x00014364 <m+16>:   st  %sp, [ %fp + -40 ]
0x00014368 <m+20>:   mov  0x1b, %g1
0x0001436c <m+24>:   stb  %g1, [ %fp + -17 ]
0x00014370 <m+28>:   clr  [ %fp + -24 ]
0x00014374 <m+32>:   ldub  [ %fp + -17 ], %g1
0x00014378 <m+36>:   sll  %g1, 0x18, %g1
0x0001437c <m+40>:   sra  %g1, 0x18, %g1
0x00014380 <m+44>:   add  %g1, 7, %g1
0x00014384 <m+48>:   srl  %g1, 3, %g1
0x00014388 <m+52>:   sll  %g1, 3, %g1
0x0001438c <m+56>:   sub  %sp, %g1, %sp
0x00014390 <m+60>:   add  %sp, 0x5c, %g1
0x00014394 <m+64>:   add  %g1, 7, %g1
0x00014398 <m+68>:   srl  %g1, 3, %g1
0x0001439c <m+72>:   sll  %g1, 3, %g1
0x000143a0 <m+76>:   st  %g1, [ %fp + -44 ]
0x000143a4 <m+80>:   mov  0x2d, %g1
0x000143a8 <m+84>:   ld  [ %fp + -44 ], %o4
0x000143ac <m+88>:   stb  %g1, [ %o4 ]
0x000143b0 <m+92>:   mov  1, %g1
0x000143b4 <m+96>:   st  %g1, [ %fp + -28 ]
0x000143b8 <m+100>:  ldub  [ %fp + -17 ], %g1
0x000143bc <m+104>:  sll  %g1, 0x18, %g1
0x000143c0 <m+108>:  sra  %g1, 0x18, %o5
0x000143c4 <m+112>:  ld  [ %fp + -28 ], %g1
0x000143c8 <m+116>:  cmp  %o5, %g1
0x000143cc <m+120>:  ble  0x14400 <m+172>
0x000143d0 <m+124>:  nop 
0x000143d4 <m+128>:  ld  [ %fp + -28 ], %g1
0x000143d8 <m+132>:  ld  [ %fp + -44 ], %o4
0x000143dc <m+136>:  add  %o4, %g1, %o5
0x000143e0 <m+140>:  ld  [ %fp + -28 ], %g1
0x000143e4 <m+144>:  add  %g1, 0x60, %g1
0x000143e8 <m+148>:  stb  %g1, [ %o5 ]
0x000143ec <m+152>:  ld  [ %fp + -28 ], %g1
0x000143f0 <m+156>:  inc  %g1
0x000143f4 <m+160>:  st  %g1, [ %fp + -28 ]
0x000143f8 <m+164>:  b  0x143b8 <m+100>
0x000143fc <m+168>:  nop 
0x00014400 <m+172>:  ldub  [ %fp + -17 ], %g1
0x00014404 <m+176>:  sll  %g1, 0x18, %g1
0x00014408 <m+180>:  sra  %g1, 0x18, %o5
0x0001440c <m+184>:  ld  [ %fp + 0x44 ], %g1
0x00014410 <m+188>:  mov  %g1, %o0
0x00014414 <m+192>:  mov  %o5, %o1
0x00014418 <m+196>:  call  0x2727c <.rem@plt>
0x0001441c <m+200>:  nop 
0x00014420 <m+204>:  mov  %o0, %g1
0x00014424 <m+208>:  st  %g1, [ %fp + 0x44 ]
0x00014428 <m+212>:  ldub  [ %fp + 0x48 ], %g1
0x0001442c <m+216>:  sll  %g1, 0x18, %g1
0x00014430 <m+220>:  sra  %g1, 0x18, %g1
0x00014434 <m+224>:  cmp  %g1, 0x2d
0x00014438 <m+228>:  be  0x1449c <m+328>
0x0001443c <m+232>:  nop 
0x00014440 <m+236>:  ldub  [ %fp + 0x48 ], %g1
0x00014444 <m+240>:  sll  %g1, 0x18, %g1
0x00014448 <m+244>:  sra  %g1, 0x18, %g1
0x0001444c <m+248>:  cmp  %g1, 0x60
0x00014450 <m+252>:  bg  0x14464 <m+272>
0x00014454 <m+256>:  nop 
0x00014458 <m+260>:  clr  [ %fp + -24 ]
0x0001445c <m+264>:  b  0x1449c <m+328>
0x00014460 <m+268>:  nop 
0x00014464 <m+272>:  ldub  [ %fp + 0x48 ], %g1
0x00014468 <m+276>:  sll  %g1, 0x18, %g1
0x0001446c <m+280>:  sra  %g1, 0x18, %g1
0x00014470 <m+284>:  cmp  %g1, 0x7a
0x00014474 <m+288>:  ble  0x14488 <m+308>
0x00014478 <m+292>:  nop 
0x0001447c <m+296>:  clr  [ %fp + -24 ]
0x00014480 <m+300>:  b  0x1449c <m+328>
0x00014484 <m+304>:  nop 
0x00014488 <m+308>:  ldub  [ %fp + 0x48 ], %g1
0x0001448c <m+312>:  sll  %g1, 0x18, %g1
0x00014490 <m+316>:  sra  %g1, 0x18, %g1
0x00014494 <m+320>:  add  %g1, -96, %g1
0x00014498 <m+324>:  st  %g1, [ %fp + -24 ]
0x0001449c <m+328>:  clr  [ %fp + -28 ]
0x000144a0 <m+332>:  ldub  [ %fp + -17 ], %g1
0x000144a4 <m+336>:  sll  %g1, 0x18, %g1
0x000144a8 <m+340>:  sra  %g1, 0x18, %o5
0x000144ac <m+344>:  ld  [ %fp + -28 ], %g1
0x000144b0 <m+348>:  cmp  %o5, %g1
0x000144b4 <m+352>:  ble  0x14568 <m+532>
0x000144b8 <m+356>:  nop 
0x000144bc <m+360>:  ld  [ %fp + 0x44 ], %g1
0x000144c0 <m+364>:  sll  %g1, 3, %l0
0x000144c4 <m+368>:  ld  [ %fp + -28 ], %o0
0x000144c8 <m+372>:  ld  [ %fp + -28 ], %o1
0x000144cc <m+376>:  call  0x272ac <.umul@plt>
0x000144d0 <m+380>:  nop 
0x000144d4 <m+384>:  mov  %o0, %g1
0x000144d8 <m+388>:  add  %l0, %g1, %g1
0x000144dc <m+392>:  add  %g1, 8, %o5
0x000144e0 <m+396>:  ldub  [ %fp + -17 ], %g1
0x000144e4 <m+400>:  sll  %g1, 0x18, %g1
0x000144e8 <m+404>:  sra  %g1, 0x18, %g1
0x000144ec <m+408>:  mov  %o5, %o0
0x000144f0 <m+412>:  mov  %g1, %o1
0x000144f4 <m+416>:  call  0x2727c <.rem@plt>
0x000144f8 <m+420>:  nop 
0x000144fc <m+424>:  mov  %o0, %g1
0x00014500 <m+428>:  st  %g1, [ %fp + -32 ]
0x00014504 <m+432>:  ld  [ %fp + -32 ], %g1
0x00014508 <m+436>:  ld  [ %fp + -44 ], %o5
0x0001450c <m+440>:  add  %o5, %g1, %g1
0x00014510 <m+444>:  ldub  [ %g1 ], %g1
0x00014514 <m+448>:  sll  %g1, 0x18, %g1
0x00014518 <m+452>:  sra  %g1, 0x18, %g1
0x0001451c <m+456>:  st  %g1, [ %fp + -36 ]
0x00014520 <m+460>:  ld  [ %fp + -32 ], %g1
0x00014524 <m+464>:  ld  [ %fp + -44 ], %o4
0x00014528 <m+468>:  add  %o4, %g1, %o5
0x0001452c <m+472>:  ld  [ %fp + -28 ], %g1
0x00014530 <m+476>:  ld  [ %fp + -44 ], %o4
0x00014534 <m+480>:  add  %o4, %g1, %g1
0x00014538 <m+484>:  ldub  [ %g1 ], %g1
0x0001453c <m+488>:  stb  %g1, [ %o5 ]
0x00014540 <m+492>:  ld  [ %fp + -28 ], %g1
0x00014544 <m+496>:  ld  [ %fp + -44 ], %o4
0x00014548 <m+500>:  add  %o4, %g1, %o5
0x0001454c <m+504>:  ld  [ %fp + -36 ], %g1
0x00014550 <m+508>:  stb  %g1, [ %o5 ]
0x00014554 <m+512>:  ld  [ %fp + -28 ], %g1
0x00014558 <m+516>:  inc  %g1
0x0001455c <m+520>:  st  %g1, [ %fp + -28 ]
0x00014560 <m+524>:  b  0x144a0 <m+332>
0x00014564 <m+528>:  nop 
0x00014568 <m+532>:  ld  [ %fp + -24 ], %g1
0x0001456c <m+536>:  ld  [ %fp + -44 ], %o5
0x00014570 <m+540>:  add  %o5, %g1, %g1
0x00014574 <m+544>:  ldub  [ %g1 ], %g1
0x00014578 <m+548>:  sll  %g1, 0x18, %g1
0x0001457c <m+552>:  sra  %g1, 0x18, %g1
0x00014580 <m+556>:  ld  [ %fp + -40 ], %sp
0x00014584 <m+560>:  mov  %g1, %i0
0x00014588 <m+564>:  ret 
0x0001458c <m+568>:  restore
```

Comment: Since you've got gdb, can you show us a disassembly? And is this homework?

Comment: homework? more like hacking ;-)     errrm, I mean  "reverse engineering for learning porpoises"

Comment: since you have the assembly, maybe try to de-compile it into some form of source code?

Comment: or maybe contact the author and ask?

Comment: this is part of my coursework to learn gdb for a computer science class - not hacking ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the disassembly:

```
gdb ./prog
b FUNCTION_NAME_HERE
r
disassemble
```

**Edit:**

The disassembly looks like SPARC.
You may want to start by checking out the stack lay-out of the SPARC architecture:

http://www.sics.se/~psm/sparcstack.html

%fp sounds like the framepointer. There are not that many load instructions using %fp. My guess would be that

```
0x000143d4 <m+128>:  ld  [ %fp + -28 ], %g1
0x000143d8 <m+132>:  ld  [ %fp + -44 ], %o4
```

are the function's arguments.

Comment: posted the disassembly, is there a way to see which assembly variables are which c variables? thanks

Comment: cool, this is not x86, it's SPARC. But how much more is there? can you post everything all the way up to the ret statement?

Comment: okay, that's all of it - quite a bit.. i see, i've done some x86 assembly before but never dealt with SPARC. how do you think I should go about understanding all this?

Comment: @Gary: if the executable has been stripped, the c variable names are not recoverable. A common trick is to give names to memory locations based on where they get used. What you are trying to do here is called reverse engineering, and it is pretty well documented http://www.ethicalhacker.net/content/view/152/24/

Comment: Justin, is it possible to step through the assembly by instruction and check the variable values? If so - could you tell me how or link me somewhere that tells me? Thanks!

Comment: 'si' will step by assembly instruction in gdb. 'i r' will show the current contents of the registers. To look at where execution is heading, you can do "print $pc ($pc)+20" (which will show the next 20 bytes of upcoming instructions). It would probably be good to make note of what is being stored in memory, and then what is done with those values, etc... the trick is figuring out reasonable names for the variables. Since you are so new to assembly, another trick is to try to write out simple c code that would compile to the existing assembly (bit by bit, through trial and error, of course).

Comment: Another thing to note is that in emacs M-x gdb-many-windows will show the current status of the registers in one panel, any automatically printed expressions in another, and your command line for interacting with gdb in another etc. which may speed up your productivity as compared to just using gdb from the command line.